# how could I get the line number by Parser ctx?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

```
public void enterStatus(Parser.Context ctx) 
{
}
```

Parser.Context ctx doesn't have the method like getLinuNumber().How could I get the parser line number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **ctx.getStart().getLine()**

> public Token getStart() Get the initial token in this context. Note
>   that the range from start to stop is inclusive, so for rules that do
>   not consume anything (for example, zero length or error productions)
>   this token may exceed stop

From the doc: http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/ParserRuleContext.html#getStart()

and

> int getLine() The line number on which the 1st character of this token
>   was matched, line=1..n

from: http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Token.html#getLine()